# Making an ldap call using spring

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm trying to search for a user using an admin account, but the admin user can't "see" people in the regular Users group. My ldapTemplate is getting authenticated properly and I can query and see all the people in the Admin account's context, but I can't see objects in the actual group I need to search, which is called "Users". Here's my ldapTemplate call:

```
private void testLookup(String username) {
    AndFilter andFilter = new AndFilter();
    andFilter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person"));
    // andFilter.and(new EqualsFilter("memberOf", "Users"));
    andFilter.and(new EqualsFilter("mail", <usernameInUsersGroup));

    final SearchControls controls = new SearchControls(); //
    controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
    List<String> list =
        ldapTemplate.search("",
                List<String> list2 = ldapTemplate.search("", andFilter.encode(), controls, new EmailAttributesMapper());
                controls,
                new EmailAttributesMapper());
}
```

The list is always empty. It SHOULD find the person in the Users group I'm searching for.  I've tried passing in a different "base" but I always get an error that it can't find the group. The only thing I don't get an error on is passing in "".

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile afaik. You have a search in a search. Please fix the code.

Comment: Fixed, cut and paste issue.

Comment: Anyone have any guidance? Is this a setup issue with the admin account?